# If someone answers a better answer but got the idea from another answer

Tags: discussion

Say someone answered [one of my questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55042315/eloquent-where-in-using-raw-query-capsule-manager) (an answer that people had a difficult time figuring out), and then someone took the answer, modified it, and gave me a cleaner answer that IS actually better, but the idea originally came from someone else. Who deserves the accepted answer? The second person as his answer was indeed better and I used it, or the first one who gave the general idea? I went for the first option. Was that wrong?

Comment: Well The first to comment about it is the one that got inspired by the other answer. More seriously There is no inspiration here. Many problem have a general solution that can be implement in different way. Every thing here is licensed under cc by-sa 3.0, there is no authorship on the idea on this question.

Comment: @xdtTransform I'm not talking about authorship, I'm rather talking about which answer deserves being accepted if one has taken the idea from another. I don't quite understand what your comment has to do with my question? Except for the first part, that yes the first one to comment the answer is his idea. In this case, the first one to answer was the first to comment as well.

Comment: The _Accepted_ checkmark doesn't mean _"best answer"_. Means _"this is the answer the asker found most helpful"_. Nothing else.

Comment: @yivi what you're saying contradicts with the answer given below tho...

Comment: Not really. What answer do you find to be most helpful? That will probably be the best answer that would help someone else when faced with a similar issue.

Comment: Imagine an question about geting the max value of an int array. The idea is pretty simple :' go throught the array, compare the value with the max'. Answer will have different level of optimisation, readability, and error handling. I would not care mutch about who was the first one to say "lets go thought the array and look at the value one by one". The only answer to this "Follow your hearth" and "the green tick was in you all along".

Comment: "an answer that people had a difficult time figuring out" is giving the question too much credit. Very basic question here. Why couldn't 2 "fastest gun in the exchange" members have answered within 10mins of each other independently?

Comment: @Jhawins because the second answer was first a comment on the first answer telling him his logic could be cleaner and gave an answer that he turned into an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What is, in your opinion, the *best* answer?
Which answer would help someone else, when faced with a similar issue?

The fact that one answer is inspired by another isn't really relevant when accepting answers. Judge them on their own qualities.

Now, if it were a case of blatant plagiarism, there'd be a good reason to flag the newer answer, but looking at this case (as someone that has no idea about eloquent), I can't see what the newer answer took from the older one.

Comment: If it's about the best answer if it's not plagia then I did right choosing the second answer. About what he took, it's the idea to fill a variable with `?, ?, ..etc` and use that variable in my select (as I wanted a native eloquent way, but he gave me a PHP workaround, that the other person took and gave me a cleaner PHP workaround).Thanks for clarifying things!